# Glue job failing when loading API files to subfolder in S3

Tags: python-3.x, aws-glue

I'm new to this.
I've created a simple Glue job with python script that send API request and load data into S3. When loading data into the top S3 bucket (s3://my-bucket) it works fine but the job fails when I change the target directory to load files into subdirectory of S3  (s3://my-bucket/log-data).
the following script works and load file mydata.txt into the bucket.

```
import request
import boto3
URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
r = requests.get(url = URL)
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',region_name='eu-west-2')
s3_client.put_object(Body=r.text, Bucket='my-bucket', Key='mydata.txt')` '
```

when I change the last line of the code to load file into the subdirectory of S3 bucket

```
s3_client.put_object(Body=r.text, Bucket='my-bucket/log-data', Key='mydata.txt')
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the prefix to the `Key` arg in `put_object`

```
import request
import boto3
URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
r = requests.get(url = URL)
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',region_name='eu-west-2')
s3_client.put_object(Body=r.text, Bucket='my-bucket', Key='log-data/mydata.txt')
```